# UITableView - AFNetworking operation in background freezes scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, afnetworking

I have a sample application with a UITableViewController.

As in the facebook newsfeed, the app is supposed to download a first time X news, and then fetch news progressively as the user scroll.

Here is my implementation :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (indexPath.row == self.newsList.count-PADDLE_BEFORE_FETCHING && !cantFetchMore)
    if (!fetching){
        fetching = YES;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            [self fetchNews];
        });


    }
```

}

(the idea is to start fetching additional news when we reach the N-PADDLE_BEFORE_FETCHING cell, only if we can still fetch some - see below- and if fetching is still not currently running)

and then the implementation of fetchNews :

```
-(void)fetchNews{


    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%d%@",HOSTNAME,GET_NEWS,[defaults objectForKey:@"oAuthToken"],@"&limit=",FETCH_SIZE_NEWS,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&offset=%d",self.newsList.count]];

    NSURLRequest *request =[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];


    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        #if DEVELOPMENT_MODE
                NSLog(@"News : %@",JSON);
                NSLog(@"Response : %@\n Request : %@",response,request);
        #endif

        //NSLog(@"Number of news fetched : %d",((NSArray*)JSON[@"data"]).count);

        for (NSDictionary *d in JSON[@"data"]){
            News *new = [[News alloc] initWithDictionary:d];
            [self.newsList addObject:new];
            new = nil;
        }


        if ((((NSArray*)JSON[@"data"]).count)%FETCH_SIZE_NEWS !=0) cantFetchMore = YES;
        //NSLog(@"%d cantFetch",cantFetchMore);

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

        [self.tableView reloadData];

        fetching = NO;

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request error : %@ %@ %@",request,error, JSON);
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        fetching = NO;

    }];


    [operation start];
```

}

This will fetch FETCH_SIZE_NEWS additional news from the server starting at the good offset which is the current size of the newsList array.
Also, if the count of fetched news % FETCH_SIZE_NEWS is different from 0, that means that we cannot fetch additional news (which will prevent from calling the webservice while scrolling the UITableView).

My issue is that when the fetching is done (exactly when I see the activity wheel running in the status bar), it blocks the GUI, and I cant continue to scroll down from the n-PADDLE_BEFORE_FETCHING cells to the n cells, or even scroll up to the previously loaded cells.

I don't really understand why as AFNetworking is supposed to run asynchronously.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: It does run asynchronously, so 2 things:
1) Don't run `fetchNews` asynchronously, let AFNetworking handle asynchronous fetching.
2) Use an `NSOperationQueue` and add `operation` to it, instead of calling `[operation start]`.
Do those and let us know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks Guy; I will try the NSOperationQueue instead. 
I was not running fetchNews async at the beginning in fact, but well I decided to try to see if it changes something... but not :)
I will let you know for the NSOperationQueue

Comment: Hi @GuyKogus, switched to NSOperationQueue... unfortunately; that does not improve that much the scrolling flow. Thanks

Comment: How many items are in `JSON`? I.e. the returned object in the success block. That foreach-loop you have is running on the main thread, which could be blocking. Also, have you tried profiling the app? That should give you a good view on what's using up the most CPU time.

Comment: Updated with an answer. If you want to post it and that I accept it as the good answer, just let me know :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for-loop in the completion block is running on the main thread and may be causing the slow-down. Try sending that code to another thread/queue.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above buy Guy Kogus, the processing within the complete block of the AFNetworking operation was adding a bit a freezer on the main thread while scrolling.

Just added

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{//processing block}
```

Within the complete block (notably the foreach loop) and this is far better.

Thanks